# Hope or no hope in Job 13:15?

Tags: hebrew, textual-criticism, grammar, job

Job 13:15a

> NRSV: See, he will kill me; I have no hope ...
>   ESV: Though he slay me, I will hope in him ...
>   BHS: הֵן יִקְטְלֵנִי לֹא [לוֹ] אֲיַחֵל

The difference rests on whether to prefer the *ketib* לא (=no), negating the verb יחל (=hope; "I have no hope"), or the *qere* (here bracketed) לו (=in him; "I [will] hope in him").<sup>1</sup> This is very different!

It looks like this verb commonly takes an adjunct with the preposition ל, so the *qere* (in him) plausible on that level. To my (very untrained) ear, it's weird to have the prepositional phrase "in him" before the verb, whereas this is the normal place for a negative particle, but I suppose anything goes in poetry. [LXX Job](http://katapi.org.uk/katapiNSBunix/Lxx/LxxHBByBC.php?B=18&C=13&Cv=1&version=Lxx) is characteristically "free" and is not obviously helpful here.

- Should we prefer the *ketiv* or *qere*?

I'm also curious, in light of the fact that we often (usually?) prefer the *qere* because (it makes more sense and) we value the reading tradition received by the Masoretes:

- Is there a difference in pronunciation that would have been heard by the Masoretes? They're the same to my ear (*lô* vs. *lōʾ* ), but there are a lot of distinctions I don't hear in Hebrew.

---

<sub>1. It also requires differing interpretations of the initial particle הן (~behold) -- "see" vs "though" -- but that is secondary to the textual issue in my mind.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## The Idea in Brief

The best reading for this verse would accept the *qere* as suggested by the Masoretic editors. That is, the following translation would capture the full essence of this verse:

> **Job 13:15**
>   <sup>15</sup> Look, he is going to kill me: I wait for him [to strike]; in the meantime, I am going to argue [my case] before Him.

Why does the *ketiv* or *qere* appear here? Like so many other places in the Hebrew Bible, the sounds of לֹו (*lô*) and לֹא (*lōʾ*) were homonymous, and therefore several instances of the *ketiv* and *qere* appear (for both words) throughout the Masoretic text.

The following paragraphs will discuss various aspects for understanding the preference for the *qere* reading of this verse.

## Discussion

**1. The words לֹא (*lōʾ*) and לֹו (*lô*) are [homophonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)**

There are two instances in the Masoretic Text ([1 Sam 2:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Sam%202%3A16&version=NASB;WLC) and [1 Sam 20:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Sam%2020%3A2&version=NASB;WLC)) where the לֹא (*lōʾ*) is to be understood in lieu of the written לֹו (*lô*) , and there are [17 instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH7BN.png) where the לֹו (*lô*) is to be understood in lieu of the written לֹא (*lōʾ*). Both words are homophonic; that is, these words sound the same but are written in a different way and have different meanings. (An example in English would be the words *to*, *two*, and *too*, which are homophones because they each are written in a different way and have different meanings.) The reason that לֹא (*lōʾ*) is more often confused for לֹו (*lô*) is because [the former](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4CPb.png) (5,184 instances) outnumber [the latter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg6nF.png) (1,026 instances) by a ratio of four-to-one in the Masoretic Text. In other words, the word לֹא (*lōʾ*) is much more common in Biblical Hebrew, and therefore very apt for homophonic confusion with the less common Hebrew word לֹו (*lô*).

**2. The Hebrew verb [יָחַל](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/lexicon.cfm?bn=12&page=1&sa=D&sntz=1&strongs=H3176&t=NASB&usg=AFQjCNHJTthSeEr8dtgFetrkgBTencmYxg) (*yachal*) means not only *to hope*, but also means *to wait***

According to [*GHCLOT*](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewchaldeelex00geseuoft#page/346/mode/2up), this verb in the  *piʿʿēl* aspect means *to expect*, *to hope*, *to wait*.
According to *[HALOT](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/402/mode/2up)*, this verb in the *piʿʿēl* aspect means *to await*.
According to *[HAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5DM3.png)*, this verb in the *piʿʿēl* aspect means *to wait*.

**3. The phrases within this verse (and throughout the entire chapter) appear to be in synonymous parallelism**

Twelve (12) of the twenty-eight (28) verses in this chapter [have the exact same accentuation according to the Masoretic Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq9kd.png). In other words, these verses in addition to the remaining verses in this chapter (with slight variations of accentuation) appear in synonymous parallelism, which the 19th Century Hebraist William Wickes described in his chapter on the dichotomy of Hebrew verse. That is, the first part of each verse is echoed by the second part of each verse, and thus the entire chapter.

Please click on the image below to enlarge, [or view the source (online)](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseonacpoet00wickuoft#page/n39/mode/2up).

[image]

In other words, the first phrase of the verse provides the main idea. The second phrase echoes the first phrase. At this point the dichotomy of the verse appears. Then the remainder of the verse (which is also comprised of two phrases) complements the first half of the verse. In summary, these phrases appear in symmetrical parallelism within the verse.

**4. The second half of the v.13 begins with the restrictive adverb [אַךְ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/lexicon.cfm?bn=12&page=1&sa=D&sntz=1&strongs=H389&t=NASB&usg=AFQjCNHJTthSeEr8dtgFetrkgBTencmYxg) (*'ak*)**

The second half of this verse begins with the Hebrew adverb [אַךְ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/lexicon.cfm?bn=12&page=1&sa=D&sntz=1&strongs=H389&t=NASB&usg=AFQjCNHJTthSeEr8dtgFetrkgBTencmYxg) (*'ak*), which is restrictive according to *[Gesenius’s Hebrew Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486443442)*. For example, Gesenius notes the following in §153.

Please click on the image below to enlarge, [or view the source (online)](https://archive.org/stream/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft#page/482/mode/2up).

[image]

This adverb may best be translated, “in the meantime,” not only because of the restrictive sense, but also to align the second half of the verse with the first half of the verse (in keeping with the synonymous parallelism noted in the previous paragraphs).

## Conclusion

Although he provided no analysis for his opinion, [Dr. Charles Caldwell Ryrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Caldwell_Ryrie) provided the following observation concerning this verse in his *[Ryrie Study Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802484727)*.

> **13:15**
>   The text is uncertain and may be translated, “He will slay me; I wait for Him (to strike)”; i.e., “I have no hope.” Or it may mean, “Though He slay me, I will not delay.” In any case, the general sense is clear: the fear of death would not deter Job from saying, “Not guilty” to God.

In summary, this discussion outline had provided four points which suggest that the best reading for this verse is to accept the *qere* as noted by the Masoretic editors.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph! I'm a teeny bit skeptical about ל- + יחל  as "wait for x [to strike]" which I think would be a usage not otherwise attested (not that this rules it out) -- it's usually "waiting on x" in a positive sense (e.g. [Job 29:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=job%2029%3A23&version=WLC;NASB)) -- but this verse is difficult and this seems to me a coherent approach.

Comment: @Susan - thank you for the feedback. There is actually [one example in the Hebrew Bible](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g8n1h.png) where the _pi'el_ stem of this verb takes the infinitive construct as its object (similar to English) with the meaning of "wait for x [to ... ]"

Comment: The verbal idea being implied is the part I was uncertain about, a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

The end of the verse is אַךְ־דְּ֝רָכַ֗י אֶל־פָּנָ֥יו אוֹכִֽיחַ, "but my ways before him I will make known (protest)." It seem to me that the beginning of the verse would best be read to necessitate that "but."  If the first part of the verse indicates a lost trust or hope, the "but" would not be there.

However, I don't think this eliminates the ketiv as a reading of the verse. Using the ketiv, the first part of the verse is a rhetorical question: "If he were to kill me would I lose hope?"

In modern Hebrew, there is no difference in pronunciation between the two.

Comment: Thanks you for your thoughts! My understanding is that  אך is not necessarily introducing a contrast, but [can be asseverative (“surely”)](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/36/mode/1up). Although to me it seems like it actually is drawing a contrast in the “no hope” scenario: “I have no hope.... yet (but) I will argue my case...",  no?

Comment: My understanding, and admittedly this reflects biases of my rabbinic training, is that אך, even when used asseveratively, always connotes a contrast to something the listener or reader might otherwise have thought ("but surely").  Furthermore, where, as here, it is used in the middle of a sentence, it seems to me that "but" is the better translation.

Comment: That being said, your point that the second part of the verse makes sense as a contrast to the lost hope/trust is well taken.